# Skip and Take: An efficient approach to OFFSET LIMIT in EF 4.1?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The following code:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    db.Blogs.First().Posts.Skip(10).Take(5).ToList();
}
```

Will generate the following SQL:

```
-- statement #1
SELECT TOP ( 1 ) [c].[Id] AS [Id],
             [c].[Title]          AS [Title],
             [c].[Subtitle]       AS [Subtitle],
             [c].[AllowsComments] AS [AllowsComments],
             [c].[CreatedAt]      AS [CreatedAt]
FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [c]

-- statement #2
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
   [Extent1].[Title]    AS [Title],
   [Extent1].[Text]     AS [Text],
   [Extent1].[PostedAt] AS [PostedAt],
   [Extent1].[BlogId]   AS [BlogId],
   [Extent1].[UserId]   AS [UserId]
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[BlogId] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */
```

(from http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0)

**NB The Skip and Take have not been translated to SQL resulting in ALL posts from the blog being loaded from the database, instead of just the 5 we require.**

This seems dangerously, horribly inefficient. Unbelievably so, what gives?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason it's happening is the call to [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535183.aspx), which is causing the `Blog` object to be materialized. Any further traversal requires more queries.

Try `db.Blogs.Take(1).SelectMany(b => b.Posts).Skip(10).Take(5).ToList();` instead to do it in one query. You probably want to add some sort of ordering of blogs before the `.Take(1)`, to ensure a deterministic result.

**Edit**
You actually have to use OrderBy before Skip (otherwise LINQ to Entities will throw an exception), which makes it something like:

```
db.Blogs.OrderBy(b => b.Id).Take(1) // Filter to a single blog (while remaining IQueryable)
    .SelectMany(b => b.Posts) // Select the blog's posts
    .OrderBy(p => p.PublishedDate).Skip(10).Take(5).ToList(); // Filter to the correct page of posts
```

Answer (score 2):

As he suggests in his post, you could use EQL to perform this query instead.  Something like:

```
// Create a query that takes two parameters.
string queryString =
    @"SELECT VALUE product FROM 
      AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product 
      order by product.ListPrice SKIP @skip LIMIT @limit";

ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery =
    new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString, context);

// Add parameters to the collection.
productQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("skip", 3));
productQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("limit", 5));

// Iterate through the collection of Contact items.
foreach (Product result in productQuery)
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}; Name: {1}",
    result.ProductID, result.Name);
```

Code taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738702.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is helpful, but I was looking for  an EQL-free solution. I should have stated that in the question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get your first blog and use the blog id to filter posts like this:

```
Blog blog = db.Blogs.First();
blog.posts = Posts.Where(r=>r.blogID=blog.id).Skip(10).Take(5).ToList();
```